# Logical Volume 100% Use but 50G Appears Free

Tags: centos, lvm, ext3

I am resizing logical volumes on a CentOS server and I have come across an issue where the volumes say that they are 100%, though the "Size" and "Used" columns seem to indicate that there should be more space.

```
df -h /volume_name
Filesystem  Size   Used  Avail  Use%  Mounted on
/dev/blah   1014G  963G  24M    100%  /volume_name
```

My resizing process, in case that is contributing to the problem, is:

```
umount /dev/volume_name
lvresize -L 1014G /dev/volume_name
e2fsck -f /dev/volume_name
resize2fs /dev/volume_name
mount /dev/volume_name /volume_name
```

Is it normal that there would be so much unused space?  When I run e2fsck on the volumes most of them say they have about 2 or 3% non-contiguous space.  Could that be contributing to the issue?

Thanks for any help you can give me.  I've tried searching for the issue but I may be using the wrong terminology, so even pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What type of FS is it? In case of ext2/3/4 if you created the FS without specifying reserved blocks, there are 5% reserved blocks by default, that's 50GB in case of 1TB filesystem.

try following:

```
tune2fs -l /dev/blah |grep -i reserved
```

These are blocks reserved for the user root - this makes sense for filesystems essential for running the OS, ie rootfs, /var, /tmp etc. but it's seriously contraproductive for /home, /apps etc...

If you want to remove the reservation, type the following:

```
tune2fs -m0 /dev/blah
```

Comment: Would there be any harm for removing reserved blocks for a volume primarily used for file storage (tiffs, xml, etc)?  

Thanks to everybody for the helpful answers, I wish I had enough street cred on the site to upvote you.  :)

Comment: the 5% reservation makes sense only on filessytems used by the operating system, as I've mentioned; if your tiffs and XML files reside on such filesystem, then I'd recommend to maybe lower the value (esp. if the filesystem is HUGE - the 5% defautl was set up when filessytems used to be MUCH smaller than nowadays, in hundreds of megabytes)... you can for example set it to 1% (-m1 instead of -m0 in the above command), if the filesystem is 10GB, 1% is still 100MB, should be enough for some emergency running of OS, but better is separate data from operating system, (ie separate /home, /opt/...).

Answer (score 1):

Execute 'dumpe2fs -h /dev/blah |grep -E "lock count"' on the system and take a look at the Block count and Reserved block count. When creating a filesystem 5% of the space is reserved for administrative purposes doing some quick math 
shows that 5% of 1014G is about 50G.
If you want to adjust this you can use the -r and -m options of the tune2fs command to do so.

Answer (score 0):

By default 5% of the blocks is reserved for the superuser, root, when you create a file-system. You can check the properties of an ext[2-4] file-system with `dump2fs`.

You can change that percentage with `-m` option of `tune2fs`, which is a common thing to do on large volumes.